# How to make users IPs safe while using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I wanted to use the WebRTC technology on my website to make a voice chat there, however, I found that this technology allows users to know other users' IP addresses. How can I fix this and hide users' IP addresses from other users?

Comment: You'd need to proxy all traffic then with a TURN server, so both users only see your TURN server and never directly each other. That's going to massively increase your cost of running the service though, as TURN servers need to be rather beefy.

Comment: how would two peers connect without knowing about each other? That's like me calling you w/o knowing your phone number. Use a VPN if worried, otherwise there's no real point in using webRTC instead of other options.

Comment: @deceze How can I set it up? Is there any article about it?

Comment: I'd start with asking how many clients you want to serve with this. Again, a TURN server will need to relay *all* traffic between peers, meaning possibly a lot of HD video streams. You can relatively easily set up a single server yourself (a popular open source TURN server is *coturn*), but if you're trying to serve dozens or hundreds or thousands of concurrent clients in production with this, you need to seriously think about scalability and that's not easy. At that point, using a commercial service would be a lot easier and probably cheaper.

Comment: @deceze I plan to have about 50-100 people connected to the voice chat on average and about 150-200 at peak. How do I connect a WebRTC client to the TURN server if I finally decide to set it up?

Comment: "*this technology allows users to know other users' IP addresses*" - so what? It's not like an IP address is a well-guarded secret or in some way a private piece of data.